# MVVM Light Message Notification occurs multiple times

Tags: c#, notifications, event-handling, mvvm-light, messagebox

I am using MVVM Light and am using Messages to communicate between ViewModels to let a view.xaml.cs know when it is ok to execute something. My problem is that I register for a message and then it receives it multiple times but first time it registers and receives only once. So to keep from my program executing something more than once I have to create boolean flags to see if it has already been received but its also not working, Is there any ideas to solve this?.

In ViewModel.cs

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("NewNameAlreadyExists"));
```

In View.xaml.cs

```
public View()
{    
    InitializeComponent();    
    Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, NotificationMessageReceived);         
}

private void NotificationMessageReceived(NotificationMessage msg)
{           
    switch (msg.Notification)
    {
        case "NewNameAlreadyExists": 
                MessageBox.Show(Properties.Resources.CopyGipsTemplateViewModel_NewNameAlreadyExists, 
                                Title, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
                break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are registering your message in the constructor of your view.
This will mean that you get a new message registration each time your view is constructed leading to the scenario that it works fine the first time the page is visited, but not thereafter.
If you breakpoint on your message registration you will be able to confirm if this is the case.

This can then be resolved by either moving your message registration, wrapping your registration with a boolean flag, or calling Message.Default.Unregister at an appropriate point.

Comment: Thanks Andy, It's working fine by registering the message inside the windows_load event of the view.